# Ошибка Nuget при установке пакета

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Приветствую!

Есть проект С# WPF. При этом постоянно выскакивает ошибка при попытке установить какой нибудь пакет через консоль диспетчера пакетов :

```
Install-Package : Unable to load the service index for source http://packagesource.
Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса.
Невозможно разрешить удаленное имя: 'packagesource'
строка:1 знак:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.4.0    
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

С чем это связано, как исправить ?

UPD

Настройки Nuget  :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @FoggyFinder да. абсолютно любой

Comment: @FoggyFinder Источник - https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/

Comment: @FoggyFinder если бы все было так просто (

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67571/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте, что у вас в Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources. Похоже, что адрес источника пакетов неверный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Адрес источника действительно неверный. Поможете решить?