# C# проект не собирается

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget

При компиляции C# проекта в Visual Studio с недавнего времени получаю ошибку Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Если ставлю прокси в NuGet Config, то тоже самое. При этом в браузере эта ссылка открывается. Что может быть не так? Windows 7

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735120/184217

Comment: источник верный