# Ошибка установки NuGet Пакета 404

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Пытаюсь установить NuGet пакет в свой проект, но ни как не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка. Указывал огромное кол-во вариаций источника, но все попытки оказались тщетны. Сейчас источник выглядит так: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasyData.AspNetCore/, но возвращает ошибку 404. В чем заключается проблема?

Comment: 404 - файл отсутствует. То есть по указанной ссылке, файла нет. Почему это так? Надо спрашивать у вас. Тут либо у вас редирект идет на свой адрес, либо провайдер блокирует NuGet, либо еще что-то подобное.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за ответ, даже не думал, что провайдер может блокировать такие вещи, как NuGet. Буду копать в этом направлении.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735120/184217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Провайдер или антивирус много чего могут блокировать, у меня антивирус бывает на проекты ругается, особенно если я запускаю в проекте новый процесс кодом. По установке данного пакета скачайте его через браузер и установите вручную https://stackoverflow.com/a/10240180/12888024