# Ошибка при запуске MSTest

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mstest

Не получается запустить модульный тест на ноутбуке. На пк все тоже самое работает.Может кто-то подскажет в чем дело? второй вечер не могу победить[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас не хватает nuget пакетов, отвечающих за тестирование(нижние 4 ошибки)

Comment: Добавил источник пакетов.
[Ошибка Nuget при установке пакета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735076/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-nuget-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0/735120#735120)